# What should I do when watched folder is renamed?

Tags: java, nio, watchservice

Tested on Windows. Watch changes in folder `a`. When I rename watched folder `a` into `b` `WatchService` still tracks changes. The problem is that `a` doesn't exist anymore. `(Path)event.context()` returns relative path to watched folder. So you now that you are watching `a` folder and file `abc.txt` was changed. But really it's placed in folder `b`.

How can I get correct absolute path to changed file?

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed your issue on Windows 7. After changing the (watched) dir name, events are reported such that the associated file name is resolved with the original dir name. This is also the case when using jpathwatch:  http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com/ or https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpathwatch/

Typically you are watching a "known" or "expected" directory such as "/myDropBox", that is not expected to change names. It would seem that if you expect that a watched dir might change its name then you would also need to register its parent directory. You would then see a "delete" event for the original name and "create" for the new name.